# Can I disable autorotation animations and still get rotation notifications?

Tags: ios

I want to implement all my own rotation animations but if I only return `YES` to `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, I no longer get `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` and `willRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` notifications.

Can I get notifications for rotations while also disabling the default rotation animations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should still be able to subscribe to `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` even if you've disabled view controller autorotation via `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old, but just thought I'd add a link to a tutorial I found when I was in the same situation you were (wanting to get notifications for device rotation without allowing views to rotate).

[This tutorial](http://the.ichibod.com/kiji/how-to-handle-device-rotation-for-uiviews-in-ios) gives a nice and simple overview of how to handle device rotation using `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`.

Comment: tutorial link is broken

Comment: @jDutton Thanks for letting me know. I just emailed the person who wrote this tutorial in case they're not aware of it.